# Getting feeds from the Facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Some time ago I got feeds from my Facebook page by the curl request like this:

```
    $url='https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.phpformat=json&id=XXXXXXXXXXXXX';

    $curl = curl_init();

    $header[0] = "Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,";
    $header[0] .= "text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
    $header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
    $header[] = "Keep-Alive: 300";
    $header[] = "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7";
    $header[] = "Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5";
    $header[] = "Pragma: "; // browsers keep this blank.

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, '');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip,deflate');
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    $json = curl_exec($curl);
```

But two days ago this script returned error with message like that http://prntscr.com/602m20

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The Pages JSON feed (e.g.
>   https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=%2019292868552&format=json)
>   is now deprecated and will stop returning data from Jan 28, 2015
>   onwards. Developers should instead call the feed edge on the Graph
>   API's Page object: /v2.2/{page_id}/feed.

[Source](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog)

Comment: When I do request to the url https://graph.facebook.com/page_id/feed in response i get the page with error http://prntscr.com/602r6x. Where i can get access token to my page.

Comment: After two hours script result get an error about expires my access_token. What is the best solution to the problem  of expired access_token?